# deleting specific part of field in firebase (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to remove part of an object in firebase. This is what it looks like in the database:

[image]

this is within a specific user id inside a 'users' collection.

The way I am currently trying to delete it:

```
  removeUserLikedProperty(property_id: string) {
    console.log(property_id)
    return fromPromise(this.usersCollection.doc(`${this._auth.currentUserId}/test/${property_id}`).delete());
  }
```

this is within my service. Then I have this in my ts file:

```
  removeUserLikedProperty(property_id: string) {
    this._user.removeUserLikedProperty(property_id);
    console.log(property_id)
  }
```

and then finally call this on click in my html:

```
<button class="button button-previous" (click)="removeUserLikedProperty(property?.property_id)">unlike</button>
```

From everything that I have read, this is my understanding of how to delete a member of a field. By accessing the users collection, getting user id, then going into 'test' and then removing the specific id. Anyone have any further knowledge on this? May syntax may be completely off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing documents and fields. Please [Read the documentation about data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

Either way, from the image what I understand you're trying to achieve is to delete a field in a nested object.

You need to know two things: [how to delete a field in a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields) and [how to access a field in a nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects)

The following should work:

```
removeUserLikedProperty(property_id: string) {
  console.log(property_id);
  return fromPromise(this.usersCollection.doc(`${this._auth.currentUserId}`).update({
      [`test.${property_id}`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! Few things. I am getting this error with this:

webpack: Failed to compile.
ERROR in src/app/shared/_services/user.service.ts(106,13): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/shared/_services/user.service.ts(106,25): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/shared/_services/user.service.ts(106,35): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/shared/_services/user.service.ts(108,6): error TS1005: ')' expected.

Comment: also, is test supposed to be a string?

Comment: Sorry, the code was hand-written. But the sintax is corrected now.